# How to do a horizontally scrollable listview?

Tags: android

I want to implement a HORIZONTALLY SCROLLABLE LISTVIEW but can't seem to find a way. Could someone give me a pointer?

I capitalized the name because the solution I'm looking for is something acts like an ordinary spread sheet, where the entire sheet scrolls vertically and horizontally. I've done some search, and found some look-alike implementations but they are not exactly what I'm looking for. So, ..., any idea? Thanks in advance.

(P.S.1 I didn't mean Paul Soucy's [horizontal ListView](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34). If I didn't get it wrong, it can have only one row. My app would have hundreds, if not thousands, rows.

P.S.2. I didn't mean each row in the ListView can be scrolled separately as seen in the answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851896/android-how-can-i-make-horizontally-scrollable-items-in-a-vertical-listview) where Mikael_S mentioned about [Droidstack](http://code.google.com/p/droidstack/).

P.S.3. I also saw solutions involving using a ScrollView embedded in another HorizontalScrollView. I can't use this either because I have to use the ListView's adapter, because there are too many rows. And for the same reason, I can't use TableLayout either.)

Thank you for reading.

Comment: would like to know the solution in case you have found any !