# ListView or ViewPager with Wider-than-screen, pinch-to-zoomable images

Tags: android

This is what I need to achieve:

Red is screen, green/blue is the images in the list view.
User should be able to scroll horizontally and vertically.
And wait, there's more - they need to be pinch-to-zoom-able...

How do I achieve that effect? (I don't wanna think about OOMEs at this point)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at :

[Android: How can I make horizontally scrollable items in a vertical listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851896/android-how-can-i-make-horizontally-scrollable-items-in-a-vertical-listview)

[How to use horizontal scroll in listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392461/how-to-use-horizontal-scroll-in-listview)

Though you can do it, it is usually a bad practice to nest a scroll view inside a listview.

Comment: And how do I make that zoomable (by tap or pinch)? And how do I tell the image views (the list view items will be images) to be wider than the screen?