# scrollbars in listview

Tags: android

in android i have add two list view and add in linear layout this linear layout add in scroll but when i scroll on listview whole layout scrollable how we can scroll specific view my xml is below

```
    android:layout_below="@+id/pvr_add">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">










        <ImageView android:id="@+id/lineshow" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/largeline"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
             </ImageView>

            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/theater_details" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

                android:layout_height="50dip">

                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/line" android:src="@drawable/line"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/lineshow"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/lineshow"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/line"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dip"
                    android:id="@+id/movie_name" android:text="English(UA)" />

                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingRight="8dip"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/lineshow"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/line"
                    android:textColor="#f8c400"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:id="@+id/theater_location" />


            </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/lineshow" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/largeline"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
             </ImageView>


        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_below="@+id/theater_details" android:id="@+id/select_date_time"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:text="Select  date and time" />

        <TableLayout android:id="@+id/weekly_show"
            android:layout_below="@+id/select_date_time" 
            android:layout_width="270dip" android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:background="@drawable/gap"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:stretchColumns="*"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        </TableLayout>



        <ListView android:layout_height="100dip"

            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector_background"
            android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:layout_width="270dip" android:layout_below="@+id/weekly_show"


            android:id="@android:id/list"></ListView>

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linear"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:paddingTop="15dip"

            android:layout_below="@android:id/list" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="270dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="270dip"
                android:layout_height="30dip" android:id="@+id/reserve_seat"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:background="@drawable/roundedcorner">
                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="12dip"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
                    android:id="@+id/seat_reqired" android:text="How many seat would you like"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                     />
                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_height="fill_parent"

                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/seekbarvalue" android:background="@drawable/noofseats" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <SeekBar android:layout_width="270dip"
            android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/reserve_seat"
                android:paddingTop="10dip" android:id="@+id/seekbar" android:max="10" />


            <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="270dip"
                android:layout_height="100dip" android:id="@+id/check_avilable_seat"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip" >
                <ListView android:layout_height="100dip"

            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector_background"

            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:layout_width="270dip" 
            android:background="@drawable/roundedcorner"


            android:id="@+id/list1"></ListView>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <Button 
     android:id="@+id/proceed"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:background="@drawable/proceed_button"
     android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
     android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
     android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="30dip"></Button>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the opening `scrollview` part of the tag...

However this question is identical to

[Android ScrollView layout problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526831/android-scrollview-layout-problem)

In short: never put listview inside scrollview.