# Programmatically scroll two ListViews (aka setSelectionFromTop is really slow)

Tags: android, listview, scroll, android-listview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scrolling with Multiple ListViews for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306626/scrolling-with-multiple-listviews-for-android)

I have two `ListView`s and I need to scroll them together by just executing the scroll on one of the `ListView`s.

I have set an `OnScrollListener` on one of the `ListView`s:

```
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
int scrollToThisPosition = firstVisibleItem;

    index = firstListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    View v = firstListView.getChildAt(0);
    top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();
    secondListView.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
}
```

Everything works just fine, besides the fact that everything is very very slow.
Does this slowness happens to anybody else? The two `ListView`s scroll smoothly without this "link" among each other, as I used the `convertView` and the holder patterns in their rows' `getView()`.