# Using a ScrollView on RelativeLayout that contains an ExpandableListView

Tags: android, scrollview, android-relativelayout, expandablelistview

I've got this `RelativeLayout` I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/screen_team_enableproximity"
            android:text="Enable proximity"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/screen_team_checkboxproximity"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/screen_team_checkboxproximity"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/screen_team_checkboxproximity"></Button>
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/screen_team_checkboxproximity"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:clickable="false"></CheckBox>
        <ExpandableListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/screen_team_teamslist"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/screen_team_availableteams"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></ExpandableListView>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/screen_team_availableteams"
            android:text="Available Teams"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_below="@+id/screen_team_getallteams"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"></TextView>
        <Button
            android:text="Create Team"
            android:id="@+id/screen_team_createteam"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/screen_team_enableproximity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="65dip"></Button>
        <Button
            android:text="Delete Team"
            android:id="@+id/screen_team_deleteteam"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/screen_team_createteam"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"></Button>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="Get available teams"
            android:id="@+id/screen_team_getallteams"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/screen_team_deleteteam"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></Button>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is I want to it to be used inside a `ScrollView` or similiar - the entire layout does not fit on the screen, especially when you add several groups to the `ExpandableListView`.

I've tried putting the `RelativeLayout` inside a `ScrollView`, but it dosn't work at all.

How do I setup a scrolling screen with my `RelativeLayout` in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put all the views above the expandable listView as listView header , and all the views below as listView footer. Then you have scrolling enabled for everything.

Comment: What do you mean by listview header and footer?

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky one. There were several discussion here on SO on how to use ScrollView with ListView. Have a look at this question: [Scrolling with Multiple ListViews for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306626/scrolling-with-multiple-listviews-for-android). The idea is to have only one list (create a custom adapter) and add headers and footers before and after your Expandable list.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from header/footer approach if you will define all the view before expandableList and give it relative position (layout_above/layout_below) , u will get the desired view .